# ServiceBus JAVA SDK advanced reloading errors, ServiceLoader (not subtype)

Tags: java, azure, jvm, osgi, serviceloader

I have an OSGi environment running some bundles, one of them uses Service Bus API (Azure Java SDK v 0.4.4) and there are some errors after I reload my OSGi environment. The workflow is this:

- Initialize the JVM and the OSGi framework
- Bundles are loaded and started
- Service Bus bundle creates a Configuration using "ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithWrapAuthentication(v,w,x,y,z)" call and everything runs smoothly
- I programmatically restart the OSGi framework and then all bundles are loaded and started again
- Service Bus bundle tries to create a Configuration using "ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithWrapAuthentication(v,w,x,y,z)" but this time I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.Builder$Exports: Provider com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.Exports not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.DefaultBuilder.create(DefaultBuilder.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:52)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.Configuration.load(Configuration.java:78)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.Configuration.getInstance(Configuration.java:63)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithWrapAuthentication(ServiceBusConfiguration.java:88)`

After some debugging I see that it could be an issue with the ServiceLoader, more exactly when it checks if the `com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.Exports` is a subclass or implements `com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.Builder$Exports` which is also being checked after during the first run.

So in my opinion there must be something that prevents the proper reload of the Services but I've not been able to figure out what's exactly happening.

Hope any of you has a clue about that!

Comment: interesting, how can I repro this? Which OSGi framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Equinox (last version), to reproduce it with not much coding create a bundle with all Service Bus SDK libraries embedded, then create a ServiceBus instance, after everything is set up, programmatically reinit the OSGi framework (can be done by calling update() method on bundle #0). Set it up again the Service Bus instance and you'll get this error by the moment the new Configuration object is being created.

To create ServiceBus instance I'm using:

`Configuration cfg = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithWrapAuthentication(v,w,x,y,z);
ServiceBusService.create(cfg);`

Answer (score 3):

ServiceLoader is part of the JRE class libs and it unware of OSGi class loading. When you restart an OSGi framework, all the bundles get new class loaders and thus the loaded classes from bundles are different class objects than before. If the ServiceLoader instance survives the framework restart, it will still be referencing the original class object.

Comment: It seems to be some issue with class loaders, I've found a workaround (I don't like it but for now it does the trick):

As ServiceLoader is using its Thread's' ContextClassLoader to resolve the services I tried to set the Thread's ContextClassLoader with my class' ClassLoader via 
`Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassThatUsesServiceBus.class.getClassLoader());` and everything started to run smoothly

Comment: This is basically what the OSGi Service Loader Mediator specification (133) does.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it's clear now why it fails. OSGi + ServiceLoaders don't like each other!