# AZURE SDK Management Services in OSGI environment

Tags: java, azure, osgi

I have an OSGi environment running, I have packed all the Azure SDK JARS in a bundle and have another bundle which uses packages exported from azure SDK bundle (Azure Java SDK v 0.9.2) and I see below errors when I try to get instance of Resource Management service.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Service or property not registered: com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.ResourceManagementClient interface com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.ResourceManagementClient 
com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder.build(DefaultBuilder.java:197)
com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration.create(Configuration.java:113)
com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.ResourceManagementService.create(ResourceManagementService.java:46)
helloazure.AzureManagement.init(AzureManagement.java:87)
helloazure.AzureClient.test(AzureClient.java:28)
```

Actually azure core builds the list of services on initialization with ServiceLoader and looks like OSGI and ServiceLoader doesn't go well hand in hand .
Then I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249008/servicebus-java-sdk-advanced-reloading-errors-serviceloader-not-subtype?answertab=active#tab-top)  which talks about success on using it and gave me some hope , I tried that workaround.   But I'm not getting different stack not the one mentioned in this post.

if any one had success with OSGI and Azure please help.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Vijay, many Azure SDK for Java users observed this error and some of the fixes are mentioned here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/465. You can try adding the build script changes using Shadow (https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) similar to what Veeresh suggested in the last post.

Hope this helps!